Activity Settings in Salesforce
I am receiving task notification created from a flow when 'Enable User Control over Task Assignment Notifications' is enabled irrespective of whether 'Send notifications for Tasks created from Flow' is enabled or not.
Can somebody tell me then what is the use of this setting? Also, same for the other settings 'Allow Flow to send delegated task notifications on records created through Apex'


Have you read the documentation? Have you enabled these task notifications in the Settings of your own user?

Yes, I have read the documentation and also enabled settings for my user

@87092 by task notifications, are you referring to email notifications or bell notifications within the app or both?

Both, email notifications and bell notifications

In Activity settings, Send notifications for Tasks created from Flow alone does not control notification bell alerts for task created from flow, you also need to check the default Notification Delivery Settings.
Go to Setup > Notification Builder > Notification Delivery Settings and verify the notification settings for tasks. By default, notification bell is enabled for task assignment. Note that disabling the task assignment notification here will prevent notification for all task assignment regardless of the source (manual, Apex, or Flow)

Allow Flow to send delegated task notifications on records created through Apex trigger notification bells to the delegated user (where task owner is different from current user) if the task is created via Apex and appropriate DML option is added, for example :
Task newTask = new Task(
    Subject = 'Task'+ System.now(),
    OwnerId ='0050N000008C1N4QAK', // Delegated user ID different than current user
    WhatId = '0010N00004AgtjIQAR', // Related record (optional)
    Status = 'Not Started'
);

Database.DMLOptions dmlOpts = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmlOpts.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true; // Trigger notification to the task owner
newTask.setOptions(dmlOpts);

insert newTask;

Now regarding email notification, these will be sent in addition to notification bell, if Activity settings Enable User Control over Task Assignment Notifications is enabled and user settings allows email to be sent.
Verify the settings under user personal settings > Calendar & Reminders > Activity Reminders > option Email me when someone assigns me a task

There is also a similar known issue here you might want to check: Record triggered flows send Task assignment emails even when Send notifications for Tasks created from Flow is unchecked
If notification settings are still not working appropriately, then it is recommended to create a case with salesforce support.
